# xpath to get data starts with specific character or string

Tags: html, xpath

I need to extract certain text elements from the following code.

```
<div class="inhalt-links">
    <h2>
        Deutsche Verkehrswacht
        <br>
        Verkehrswacht Dortmund e. V.
        <br>
    </h2>
    <h3>
        Standnummer:&nbsp;
            <span style="font-weight: normal;">4.E08</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <br>
    Benediktinerstraße 82
    <br>
    44287&nbsp;Dortmund
    <br>
    Deutschland
    <br>
    <br>
    Tel.:+49 231 447687
    <br>
    Fax:+49 231 447136
    <br>
    E-Mail:info@verkehrswacht-dortmund.de
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.verkehrswacht-dortmund.de" class="url" target="_blank">www.verkehrswacht-dortmund.de</a>
    <br>
    <div class="social"></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

For extracting the Tel.:+49 231 447687, i can use `div[@class='inhalt-links']/text()[4]`. And for other details like Fax, Email, Website, i just need to change the position number of text() element. But, the position of these texts will be of different order sometimes, like in the following code:

```
<div class="inhalt-links">
    <h2>
        DEW21
        <br>
    </h2>
    <h3>
        Standnummer:&nbsp;
            <span style="font-weight: normal;">4.B56</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <br>
    Günter-Samtlebe-Platz 1
    <br>
    44135&nbsp;Dortmund
    <br>
    Postfach:104141
    <br>
    44041&nbsp;Dortmund
    <br>
    Deutschland
    <br>
    <br>
    Tel.:+49 231 544-0
    <br>
    Fax:+49 231 544-1130
    <br>
    E-Mail:vertrieb@dew21.de
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.dew21.de" class="url" target="_blank">www.dew21.de</a>
    <br>
    <div class="social"></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

The xpath `div[@class='inhalt-links']/text()[4]` will select the text "44041 Dortmund" instead of Tel.:+49 231 544-0. Is there any xpath like `"div[@class='inhalt-links']/text[starts with "Tel.:"]"` to select the `Tel.:`element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *" Is there any xpath like `"//div[@class='inhalt-links']/text[starts with "Tel.:"]"` to select the `Tel.:` element?"*

Sure, try this way :

```
//div[@class='inhalt-links']/text()[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Tel.:')]
```

The XPath returns *text node* -rather than element- that starts with, after removing leading and trailing whitespaces*, the keyword `Tel.:`.

---

*) For reference of what `normalize-space()` is doing more precisely :

> The `normalize-space` function strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the resulting string. [[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space)]